# How to keep active state on anchor links?

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, anchor

Preview: http://cssdeck.com/labs/w7bzvb5r

Is it possible to keep the navigation link active once clicked and inactive when not selected? I would like it to change color based on which link is selected. For example, on mouse-over it changes from black to blue. How can it stay blue when it is active and black when inactive?

Comment: You can use the `visited` selector for CSS.

Comment: Would that work for something like this?

http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/else/cssnav/products.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are after is to keep the text of the link on the active page in a certain style the answer is it is possible.

There are many ways to approach this. Based on the example provided replacing this:

```
#firstPage { color: #eee; }
#firstPage/slide2 { color: #ddd; }
#firstPage/slide3 { color: #aaa; }
#firstPage/slide4 { color: #ccc; }
```

with the following will work:

```
.fp-viewing-firstPage nav#main a:nth-child(1) { color: #eee; }
.fp-viewing-firstPage-slide2 nav#main a:nth-child(2) { color: #ddd; }
.fp-viewing-firstPage-slide3 nav#main a:nth-child(3) { color: #aaa; }
.fp-viewing-firstPage-slide4 nav#main a:nth-child(4) { color: #ccc; }
```

This is using CSS3 selectors referenced here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

`.fp-viewing-firstPage` is a class applied to your `<body>` that changes on navigation.

Setting the id or class on each link is another option.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. I am working with a template I found so I wasn't too familiar with how everything in it worked. : )